# Regular expression in java to replace a pattern in multiple lines

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to replace this file input to a html table:

```
        ip add                  St Stat  Type Mode   ip only       class  numbers   
 ------------------------------ -- ----- ---- ---- --------------- ------ -----  
 ABC_127.562.200.5/32           -    up  ABC  -    127.562.200.5          5      
 ABC_127.292.200.3/32           -    up  ABC  -    127.562.200.5          4      
 ABC_127.262.200.13/32          -    up  ABC  -    127.562.200.5          3  
 ABC:jdnsajkds
```

I know this will end with "ABC" but I am not able to figure out why "/" is also coming in input

```
import java.util.regex.*;


interface LogExample {

    public static final int NUM_FIELDS = 7;


    public static final String logEntryLine = "ABC_127.562.200.5/32 **space**        -- **space**    up **space**  ABC **space** -- **space**    127.562.200.5 **space**         5 **space** ";

}


public class LogRegExp implements LogExample {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        String logEntryPattern = "";//thats i am not getting

        System.out.println("Using RE Pattern:");
        System.out.println(logEntryPattern);

        System.out.println("Input line is:");
        System.out.println(logEntryLine);

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(logEntryPattern);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(logEntryLine);
        if (!matcher.matches() || 
                NUM_FIELDS != matcher.groupCount()) {
            System.err.println("Bad log entry (or problem with RE?):");
            System.err.println(logEntryLine);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("name + IP Address: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("status1: " + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("status2: " + matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println("type: " + matcher.group(4));
        System.out.println("mode: " + matcher.group(5));
        System.out.println("IP Address: " + matcher.group(6));
        System.out.println("class: " + matcher.group(7));
        System.out.println("numbers: " + matcher.group(8));

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 @EugeneKuleshov for improving his chances to get an answer :)

Comment: What have you tried already?  It sounds like you have some code that splits the input on whitespace, but it is being tripped up by the slash character in the first column.

Comment: no actually i have no idea what to do with this.
but this is output from one file. which will end with "ABC : "+some string.

Comment: can anyone just provide one regex which will parse these 6 different collumns according to their values

Comment: @devilsam: regular expressions match strings, they do not "parse" them - your program should do that. What *exactly* are you trying to do? Show us your current code and tell us what it does and what exactly you *want it* to do...

Comment: @thkala,@David Gorsline
this is the code i am trying

Comment: `(\S+)(?:\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)(?:\s+(\S+))?)?`; you will need to test if there are >1, 7, or 8 matching groups to accomodate your all_but_first_null and column_7_null cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since your class column is blank, we can't do very much to extract that information.  But this regex will match the 7 columns of data that you do have:

```
    String logEntryPattern = "(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)";
```

We need to escape the backslash in the Java string literal.

```
    System.out.println("name + IP Address: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("status1: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("status2: " + matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("type: " + matcher.group(4));
    System.out.println("mode: " + matcher.group(5));
    System.out.println("IP Address: " + matcher.group(6));
    System.out.println("numbers: " + matcher.group(7));
```

Frankly, a regular expression is a little much for what you're trying to so -- just tokenizing on spaces would work just as well -- but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        // String line = "MSEM-E-031_TO_RVBC-R-001_T1    en   up  TE   ingr 124.252.200.2   ELSP   0";
        // String pattern = "((\\-{8})+.*?)";
        String line = "ADR-SSF-1008-M008              vlan  en dn 10081008";
        String pattern = "((\\-{6})+.*?)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find( ))
        {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```